# Docker command not working in Git Bash on Windows (exec: "com.docker.cli": executable file not found in %PATH%)

Tags: git, docker, path, git-bash, docker-cli

I have Docker Desktop for Windows and Git (including Git Bash) installed on my computer. The `docker` command works in the Command Prompt and in Powershell, but not in Git Bash. When I run the `docker` command in Git Bash, I get the following error.

```
exec: "com.docker.cli": executable file not found in %PATH%
Current PATH : ...;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;D:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;...
```

I need to get Docker to work via Git Bash to run `.sh` files containing `docker` commands with Git Bash. I can't find any reason for this error to occur.

`...` are other paths which are in `PATH`, but which are not connected to Git Bash or Docker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered similar situation, where docker tools were in the used path but for some reason calling docker ended up with the same error message.

The solution in our case was to move the docker path higher in the list in **System Properties** -> **Advanced** -> **Environment Variables** -> **System Variables** -> **Path** -> **Edit...**

I assume that the problem was that in this case path was so long, that it got cut when delivered to the called process and in this process, end of the path was lost so tooling couldn't find the *com.docker.cli* anymore in the path. And moving docker path higher in the list makes it appear earlier in the path -variable.
However, the path needs to be really long, with the length of the `$PATH` of 1200 characters, it works just fine, but problematic length in this case was around 2500 characters.

Comment: Wow, after moving the docker path higher it worked instantly. You can't imagine how long I tried to fix this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Run `echo $PATH` in git bash and see if docker is available in path. Add it to the path, if not available.

It will solve the problem.